# how to change activity transparency dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to change the transparency of activity dynamically when I move the root element/view. How to do that?. I'm creating a module for which when user slide down the whole UI down to half of the screen vertically to finish the activity. But by default when the user slides down the layout default color white of activity is shown and when I set its theme to transparent previous activity is shown. I want to change the opacity of activity window dynamically when user slides down.

Answer (score 0):

use this where you need:

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: But I want to change opacity dynamically according to the distance user slides the layout

Comment: @sasuke then use the second line where you update your slide and use different Colors to do so dynamically